# Performing wait function

Tags: java, android, delay, wait

I am discovering peers in WiFi Direct and then connecting to all of the peers and I want to perform wait function before connecting to peers because it take some time to discover peers,Please help me know how to perform wait function in android.

Comment: If you'd like the discovery to run for some predefined time before stopping, you can post a runnable with a delay that when executed, ends the discovery.  Use a the View post methods, or a handler http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: usually there are listeners for that sort of things